# React native move element

Tags: react-native

I would like to creat an element (button or image) on action. i would like seeing  it moving  on the screen and stop when i press it.

I easily found a solution for give a random position to one button (using math.random) but i don’t understand how can i put it on action (moving on the screen).

I try to put the creation of the button on a function but i can’t do a loop on a view so this doesn’t worked. Or, if it is working, this created a lot of buttons and not just one moving on the screen.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.index = true;
}

renderButton = () => {
    if (this.index){
        const NumberHolder = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600) ;
        const NumberHolder2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250) ;
        const bt = [];
        bt.push(<View style={{position: 'absolute', top: NumberHolder, left: NumberHolder2}}>
        <Button
            title="Press me 2 =>"
            onPress={this._onPressButton}
        />
        </View>);
        return bt;
    }
}

render() {
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.renderButton()}
    </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Please show ~10 lines of basic code you've written, to build on

Comment: You can use the [Animated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html) library to move things around.

Comment: ok I added it, this code allow to create a button on a random position